# wicked_pdf gem throws Runtime error on Windows

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

`` RuntimeError at /reports/1/print
Bad wkhtmltopdf's path: bundler: command not found: which
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install` ``

Error is happening when `render pdf: "pdf_name"` is called inside the controller.

Gems I am using - `rails 4.2`, `wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.9.9.3`, `wicked_pdf 0.11.0`.

I don't understand what the error means and how I can resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

After downloading and installing [wkhtmltopfd](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) directly in C drive (move it out if its inside program files), make a wicked_pdf.rb in intializers dir with this code in it: 
`WickedPdf.config = {
    #:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
    #:layout => "pdf.html",
    :exe_path => 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
}` 
Restart the rails server and its must be fixed :)

Comment: That answer helped me understanding the issue... But I fixed it using a symbolic link instead of modifying the config file.